# FORXML SQL Group By Element

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, for-xml

I am trying to group some elements together under one node. This is my current SQL;

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = (
select (
    select
        'DERIVED' '@type', 
        m.NuixDerivedFieldName '@name', (
        SELECT
            NuixFieldType as 'metadata/@type',
            NuixFieldName as 'metadata/@name'
        from eddsdbo.MetadataMapping m1
        where m1.NuixDerivedFieldName = m.NuixDerivedFieldName
        for xml path ('first-non-blank'), type
    )
from (select distinct NuixDerivedFieldName from eddsdbo.MetadataMapping) m
for xml path ('metadata'))
)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://nuix.com/fbi/metadata-profile')
select @xml for XML PATH ('metadata-list'), ROOT ('metadata-profile')
```

Which gives me the following output;

```
<metadata-profile xmlns="http://nuix.com/fbi/metadata-profile">
  <metadata-list>
      <metadata type="DERIVED" name="Barcode" xmlns="">
          <first-non-blank>
              <metadata type="CUSTOM" name="Barcode" />
          </first-non-blank>
          <first-non-blank>
              <metadata type="EVIDENCE" name="Barcode" />
          </first-non-blank>
      </metadata>
```

I want to group together elements together which have the same 'name' attribute of the metadata element under the `<first-non-blank>` element.

The desired output should be;

```
    <metadata-profile xmlns="http://nuix.com/fbi/metadata-profile">
      <metadata-list>
          <metadata type="DERIVED" name="Barcode" xmlns="">
              <first-non-blank>
                  <metadata type="CUSTOM" name="Barcode" />
                  <metadata type="EVIDENCE" name="Barcode" />
              </first-non-blank>
          </metadata>
...
```

My database looks something like this;

```
NuixFieldName                  NuixFieldType                  NuixDerivedFieldName
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
_EmailEntryID                  PROPERTY                       EmailEntryID
Audited                        Audited                        Audited
Author                         PROPERTY                       Author
Barcode                        CUSTOM                         Barcode
Barcode                        EVIDENCE                       Barcode
```

I would also like to remove the `xlmns` namespace identifier from the `metadata` elements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   NuixFieldName varchar(20),
   NuixFieldType varchar(20),
   NuixDerivedFieldName varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
  ('_EmailEntryID','PROPERTY','EmailEntryID'),
  ('Audited',      'Audited ','Audited'),
  ('Author ',      'PROPERTY','Author '),
  ('Barcode',      'CUSTOM  ','Barcode'),
  ('Barcode',      'EVIDENCE','Barcode')

DECLARE @xml XML

  SET @xml = (
  SELECT 
     -- sd.NuixDerivedFieldName AS [@name],
      'DERIVED' AS [@type],
      sd.NuixDerivedFieldName AS [@name],
      (
        SELECT 
         sd2.NuixFieldType as '@type',
         sd2.NuixFieldName as '@name' 
        FROM @SampleData sd2 WHERE sd2.NuixDerivedFieldName = sd.NuixDerivedFieldName
        FOR XML PATH ('metadata'),ROOT('first-non-blank'), TYPE
      )
  FROM (select DISTINCT sd.NuixDerivedFieldName from @SampleData sd ) sd
  FOR XML PATH('metadata'), ROOT('metadata-list'),TYPE
)  

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://nuix.com/fbi/metadata-profile')
SELECT @xml FOR XML PATH (''),ROOT('metadata-profile')
```

return:

```
    <metadata-profile xmlns="http://nuix.com/fbi/metadata-profile">
 <metadata-list>
   <metadata type="DERIVED" name="Audited">
    <first-non-blank>
      <metadata type="Audited " name="Audited" />
    </first-non-blank>
   </metadata>
   <metadata type="DERIVED" name="Author ">
    <first-non-blank>
      <metadata type="PROPERTY" name="Author " />
    </first-non-blank>
   </metadata>
   <metadata type="DERIVED" name="Barcode">
    <first-non-blank>
      <metadata type="CUSTOM  " name="Barcode" />
      <metadata type="EVIDENCE" name="Barcode" />
    </first-non-blank>
   </metadata>
   <metadata type="DERIVED" name="EmailEntryID">
    <first-non-blank>
      <metadata type="PROPERTY" name="_EmailEntryID" />
    </first-non-blank>
   </metadata>
 </metadata-list>
</metadata-profile>
```

Comment: Perfect! How would I remove the xmlns tag from the metadata elements?

Comment: Almost there, just need to remove the `:df` now :)

Comment: So the xmlns tag is now present on the `<metadata-list>` element. It needs to be removed from there also